# Nginx configure to handle request from Redis

Tags: nginx, redis

I'm trying to configure handle request direct from nginx using redis cache, cache already added to redis the problem is to configure nginx get the cache from redis

URL is like http://example.com/action.js?param1=10&param2=text

Redis key is depend on param1

in the following example it use the full path as the key for redis

so i want to capture the param1 to get key which is like "cahced_page_"+param1

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name your.website.com;
  root /home/appuser/app/current/public;
  error_log /dev/null crit; #real man don't log
  location / {
      set $redis_db "1";
      set $redis_key $uri;
      default_type   text/html;
      redis_pass redis;
      error_page 404 405 502 504 = @fallback;
  }

  location @fallback {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      if (!-f $request_filename) {
          proxy_pass http://yourunicornupstream;
          break;
      }
  }

}
```

Comment: Did you check http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#Variables ?
-> Especially the part about $arg_PARAMETER ?

Answer (score 1):

from http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpEchoModule#Variables

```
location = /code.js {
  set $redis_db "1";
  set $redis_key "hashed_key_$arg_param1";
  default_type   text/javascript;
  redis_pass redis;
  error_page 404 405 502 504 = @fallback;
}
```